# Salt at the table during a meal

Tags: sources-mekorot, meal-seudah, salt

Concerning salt brought to the table at a meal, [Tosafot](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Berakhot.40a.1.1) cites a medrash, which I can't seem to find, which states that salt is a "protector".
I know what the [covenant with salt](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.2.13.1) is; but how is salt a guardian against evil spirits?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It protects food from spoiling?

Comment: See also Ezra 4:14, "we salt the salt of the palace" is interpreted by some as "we seek the preservation of the kingdom." https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.4.14?ven=Rabbi_Mike_Feuer,_Jerusalem_Anthology&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en

Comment: See notes 86,93,94 which explain that Tosfos is probably the source. There isn't really a Midrash that says this. The sources also refer to a tradition of gentiles, who say that salt protects from demons. See the notes: https://efrata.emef.ac.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/7-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%9F.pdf

Comment: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=55868

Comment: The footnote in 86 says it is probably borrowed from non-jewish environment and Tosfos is probably the best source. It also refers to the Yerushalmi, but that's it. The Gra also says Tosfos is the best source [see here](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=55868)

Comment: @Shalom No it protects from sin. As Tosafot explains.

Comment: @Shababnik did you look at the footnotes and sources? It basically answers your question imho.

Comment: In middle of looking... Who is the author of that paper? I would also like to confirm his sources.Yes it does seem to answer my question. ThanQ.

Comment: See top of article. אדמיאל קוסמן

Comment: Oh... thank you.

Comment: FYI - Midrash also mentioned in Mishnah Berurah 167:32 - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.167.32?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Dov yeah I saw that. It's verbatim of the Tosafot I linked

Answer (score 1):

Joshua Trachtenberg's classic, Jewish Magic and Superstition: A Study in Folk Religion (1939), discusses this topic. Unfortunately it is one of the sections that is poorly footnoted, so you may have to dig further. However it should give you some context (pp. 160-161):

> Salt was another such substance which figured prominently in the
> folklore of European peoples, Thus it was believed that salt is never
> found at the witches’ Sabbat feast, and the Inquisitor and his
> assistants at a witch-trial were warned to wear bags containing
> consecrated salt for protection against the accused, Jewish folklore
> credited salt with an equally high potency. In Ezek. 16:4 we learn,
> that new-born babes were rubbed with salt, a practice sill current in
> the Orient. According to medieval authorities, salt must be set on a
> table before a meal is begun "because it protects one against Satan’s
> denunciations.” The Kabbalists were more outspoken: “It drives off the
> spirits,” they wrote, "because it is the mathematical equivalent of
> three Y-H-V-H's; therefore one should dip the piece of bread over
> which the Benediction is recited, three times into salt.” “After each
> meal eat some salt and you will not be harmed.” For this reason, salt
> was used in many rites connected with birth, marriage, and death, and
> in medicine. Very often salt and bread were jointly prescribed to
> defeat the stratagems of spirits and magicians, When a witch assaults
> a man, he can bring about her death by forcing her to give him some of
> her bread and salt. Murderers ate bread and salt immediately after
> their crime to prevent the return of their victim’s spirit to wreak
> vengeance upon them. Schudt reports that a Jewish woman advised, him
> to hang bread and salt on his daughter’s neck to protect her from
> harm; “she had done this to all her children and in consequence they
> had all prospered.” The common practice of bringing salt and bread
> into a new home before moving in, usually explained as symbolic of the
> hope that food may never be lacking there, was probably also in origin
> a means of securing the house against the spirits.